# Sending array of data as email

Tags: php, arrays, email

I have a PHP array, and I need to test the content of that array via an email. I'm aware that we can see the entire array using `var_dump()`, but how can I send that output in an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with following code, it will show the complete array clearly

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: That way needs ob_start(); echo...print...echo...; $message=ob_get_content(); ob_end_clean();

Comment: the second answer is better. This one does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 76):

You can use `print_r( $array, true )` to get the output as  a string. You can then pass this into your message body. The second paramter instructs the method to return the value rather than output it directly, permitting you to handle the results.

```
$message = "Results: " . print_r( $array, true );
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer based on the OP's question? This allows you to test it in email, not just echo out on screen.
Thanks @Sampson for this solution.

Comment: Don't forget to surround it by "<pre>" to give it even better formatting as per Frankey's answer below.

Comment: Thank you Sampson

Answer (score 8):

First Convert your array string using foreach() or implode function. I am using foreach to convert array  to string..

Where string will be key and value pairs.

```
$data = '';
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    $data .= $key.'-------'.$value;
    $data.= "\n";
}
```

or use following code to convert array to string.

```
$data = implode("\n", $array);
```

Now send that using php mail function.

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $data, $headers);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mail('email@domain.com', 'array data', '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message);
```

Comment: Thank you!! Was missing the <pre>